# HTTP byte ranges and multipart/byteranges alternatives?

Tags: http, range, multipart, rfc2616

rfc2616 (HTTP/1.1):

> A response to a request for a single range MUST NOT be sent using the
>   multipart/byteranges media type.
>
> A response to a request for multiple ranges, whose result is a single
>   range, MAY be sent as a multipart/byteranges media type with one part.
>
> A client that cannot decode a multipart/byteranges message MUST NOT
>   ask for multiple byte-ranges in a single request.

If I understand this correctly, multiple ranges in a single request MAY use multipart/byteranges and clients MUST be able to decode it or shouldn't request it at all.

Does the "MAY" imply that there are also alternatives to multipart/byteranges that could be used? Do any exist? If so, are there headers to request them?

For example, could a server potentially concatenate all byte ranges into a single part response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a request asks for multiple ranges and the server can concatenate the requested ranges into a single continuous range, then the response can either:

- use `multipart/byteranges` with a single MIME part for the concatenated range, where the part has its own `Content-Range` header.
- send the concatenated data by itself and include a top-level `Content-Range` header.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my experience back in 2012, I would reommend to stick to the first, i.e. "A response to a request for a single range MUST NOT be sent using the multipart/byteranges media type." because some clients will choke.

Comment: It can also be the other way round - Electron Updater for Node (as for 2021-07-29) assumes a single-range response to be invalid and falls back to a full download of the requested file.